# Can't access block.data on Editor.js

Tags: javascript, editorjs

I'm building a tune tool and I can't access the block data, but the block id is there and its passed on. Data is correct when instantiating the editor. I see the blocks just fine, I don't understand how data is logging undefined.

```
export default class MyBlockTune {
    static get isTune() {
        return true;
    }

    constructor({ api, data, config, block }) {
        //super({ api, data, config, block }); // Se estiver a estender outra classe
        this.api = api;
        this.data = data;
        this.config = config;
        this.block = block;
        
    }

    render() {
        return {
            icon: '<svg>...</svg>', // Place your SVG markup here
            label: 'My tune',
            onActivate: async () => {
                console.log('Block Data: ', this.block.data);
                console.log('Block ID: ', this.block.id);
                console.log('editorInstance: ', this.editorInstance); // Aqui tens acesso à instância do editor (this.editorInstance

                const blockIndex = this.api.blocks.getCurrentBlockIndex();
                console.log('Block Index: ', blockIndex);
                if (blockIndex !== null && blockIndex !== undefined) {
                    const block = this.api.blocks.getBlockByIndex(blockIndex);
                    if (block) {
                        console.log('Block: ', block);
                        const blockID = block.id;
                        console.log('Block ID: ', blockID);
                        if (block.data) {
                            console.log('Block data: ', block.data);
                        } else {
                            console.log('No data found in this block.');
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log('No block found at this index.');
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('No block index found.');
                }
                //alert('Triggered!');
                this.changeBlockText(); // Keep this as it was
            },
        };
    }
```

I'm able to change the block text, however I have no way to return it since I can't acces .data

I've tried looking at the objet log and indeed there is no .data on it. Why is this not being passed to the tune? What am I missing?

Comment: this.api = api;
        this.data = data;
        this.config = config;
        this.block = block;
        console.log('Constructor called');
        console.log('Constructor data:', data);
        console.log('Constructor block:', block);
        // Set up a listener for when the block data might change
    }

Data is undefined at constructor